# Is there a way to use slide toggle from a footer while keeping scroll position at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm working on a footer for a site that has a button which expands the footer to show/hide some more information (so regular footer on the bottom, expanded section above that). I'm just using a basic slideToggle now, but the problem is this scrolls the screen away from the bottom position (where it was when the toggle is clicked) so it gives the appearance of it sliding down rather than up. Is there a way to force the scroll position to stick to the bottom so the content is sliding in and everything is visible?

Thanks in advance everyone, this has been driving me nuts and I'm feeling kind of stuck!

Some more specifics -

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Random Content</p>
  <footer>
    <div class="expand-me">
      <p>Extra Info Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-footer">
      <p>Main Footer Stuff</p>
      <a class="expand">Expand!</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-footer {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand-me {
  display: none;
  background-color: purple;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$( ".expand" ).click(function() {
  $( ".expand-me" ).slideToggle();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvmzwB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done this by forcing window to scroll to bottom of the page.

```js
$( ".expand" ).click(function() {
  $( ".expand-me" ).slideToggle(function(){
     var height = $('#mydiv').height();
       if($(this).is(':visible')){
           $(document).scrollTop($(document).height()-$('.expand-me').height());
       }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.main-footer {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand-me {
  display: none;
  background-color: purple;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc viverra ultrices tellus, eget sollicitudin nibh elementum eu. Cras at metus ut arcu lacinia faucibus. Proin quis leo ut turpis fermentum lacinia nec nec augue. Donec commodo libero eget mi dignissim, quis mattis nibh congue. Ut dignissim condimentum porta. Curabitur feugiat condimentum nisi, a fermentum massa. Nulla blandit fringilla bibendum. Nullam auctor, quam a mollis cursus, nibh nunc fermentum ipsum, vitae tincidunt felis ante at sem. Mauris pharetra porttitor erat.</p>

<p>Duis et nulla malesuada, dictum nunc a, fermentum neque. Sed et purus non lacus rutrum tristique. Sed euismod sagittis commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ipsum justo, commodo sodales augue sit amet, convallis facilisis ligula. Suspendisse molestie, quam et porta eleifend, turpis ligula facilisis erat, at eleifend urna augue vel augue. Maecenas ut lorem dolor. Vestibulum tempor malesuada aliquet.</p>

<p>Aliquam quis mauris non erat sagittis fermentum. Morbi sed feugiat est. Donec interdum tellus id libero porttitor, sed porta nunc viverra. Curabitur lobortis elit non eros consectetur, ut faucibus magna lacinia. Sed ipsum nisl, viverra vehicula ipsum et, fringilla scelerisque libero. Donec sit amet justo sit amet lorem sodales fermentum ut sed neque. Aliquam ornare ornare ex, vel rhoncus erat hendrerit ut. Fusce placerat, dolor in facilisis tristique, magna est ullamcorper lectus, sed molestie dolor felis eu est. Cras aliquam sed ante nec pellentesque. Vestibulum lectus odio, vestibulum iaculis ante sed, cursus ullamcorper sapien.</p>

<p>Mauris at tellus a massa posuere ornare. Duis at euismod nunc. Sed pellentesque elit non diam eleifend, vitae pretium lectus dapibus. Praesent nec ex mi. Vestibulum consectetur eros nunc, in varius tortor facilisis eget. Maecenas ac sapien sit amet magna gravida mollis vel feugiat risus. Donec consectetur tincidunt dui, sed laoreet nisi lobortis in. Nam sollicitudin lorem finibus, rhoncus nunc nec, rutrum dolor. Etiam pellentesque risus eu magna accumsan dapibus. Pellentesque placerat sit amet sapien sed congue. Quisque eu bibendum libero, id pellentesque enim. Donec vel nisl eu tellus varius tempus.</p>

<p>Nulla vestibulum a nulla ac aliquam. Donec eu nisl porta, convallis lectus eu, hendrerit libero. Morbi viverra lorem ut tellus tincidunt mattis. Curabitur nisi nulla, faucibus ut tempor non, varius sit amet nibh. Fusce nulla tortor, convallis non ex ac, rhoncus dictum augue. Fusce maximus dui vitae lacus elementum, condimentum fermentum ex consectetur. Vivamus et sapien posuere, tristique massa sed, sodales nisl. Mauris est arcu, lacinia quis rutrum molestie, scelerisque in eros.</p>
  <footer>
    <div class="expand-me">
      <p>Extra Info: Donec eu nisl porta, convallis lectus eu, hendrerit libero. Morbi viverra lorem ut tellus tincidunt mattis. Curabitur nisi nulla, faucibus ut tempor non, varius sit amet nibh. Fusce nulla tortor, convallis non ex ac, rhoncus dictum augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-footer">
      <p>Main Footer Stuff</p>
      <a class="expand">Expand!</a>
    </div>
    
  </footer>
</div>
```

or like this one

```js
$( ".expand" ).click(function() {
  $( ".expand-me" ).slideToggle(function(){
     var height = $('.expand').height();
       if($('.expand-me').is(':visible')){
           $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 'slow');
       }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.main-footer {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand-me {
  display: none;
  background-color: purple;
  padding:20px;
}
.expand {
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc viverra ultrices tellus, eget sollicitudin nibh elementum eu. Cras at metus ut arcu lacinia faucibus. Proin quis leo ut turpis fermentum lacinia nec nec augue. Donec commodo libero eget mi dignissim, quis mattis nibh congue. Ut dignissim condimentum porta. Curabitur feugiat condimentum nisi, a fermentum massa. Nulla blandit fringilla bibendum. Nullam auctor, quam a mollis cursus, nibh nunc fermentum ipsum, vitae tincidunt felis ante at sem. Mauris pharetra porttitor erat.</p>

<p>Duis et nulla malesuada, dictum nunc a, fermentum neque. Sed et purus non lacus rutrum tristique. Sed euismod sagittis commodo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ipsum justo, commodo sodales augue sit amet, convallis facilisis ligula. Suspendisse molestie, quam et porta eleifend, turpis ligula facilisis erat, at eleifend urna augue vel augue. Maecenas ut lorem dolor. Vestibulum tempor malesuada aliquet.</p>

<p>Aliquam quis mauris non erat sagittis fermentum. Morbi sed feugiat est. Donec interdum tellus id libero porttitor, sed porta nunc viverra. Curabitur lobortis elit non eros consectetur, ut faucibus magna lacinia. Sed ipsum nisl, viverra vehicula ipsum et, fringilla scelerisque libero. Donec sit amet justo sit amet lorem sodales fermentum ut sed neque. Aliquam ornare ornare ex, vel rhoncus erat hendrerit ut. Fusce placerat, dolor in facilisis tristique, magna est ullamcorper lectus, sed molestie dolor felis eu est. Cras aliquam sed ante nec pellentesque. Vestibulum lectus odio, vestibulum iaculis ante sed, cursus ullamcorper sapien.</p>

<p>Mauris at tellus a massa posuere ornare. Duis at euismod nunc. Sed pellentesque elit non diam eleifend, vitae pretium lectus dapibus. Praesent nec ex mi. Vestibulum consectetur eros nunc, in varius tortor facilisis eget. Maecenas ac sapien sit amet magna gravida mollis vel feugiat risus. Donec consectetur tincidunt dui, sed laoreet nisi lobortis in. Nam sollicitudin lorem finibus, rhoncus nunc nec, rutrum dolor. Etiam pellentesque risus eu magna accumsan dapibus. Pellentesque placerat sit amet sapien sed congue. Quisque eu bibendum libero, id pellentesque enim. Donec vel nisl eu tellus varius tempus.</p>

<p>Nulla vestibulum a nulla ac aliquam. Donec eu nisl porta, convallis lectus eu, hendrerit libero. Morbi viverra lorem ut tellus tincidunt mattis. Curabitur nisi nulla, faucibus ut tempor non, varius sit amet nibh. Fusce nulla tortor, convallis non ex ac, rhoncus dictum augue. Fusce maximus dui vitae lacus elementum, condimentum fermentum ex consectetur. Vivamus et sapien posuere, tristique massa sed, sodales nisl. Mauris est arcu, lacinia quis rutrum molestie, scelerisque in eros.</p>
  <footer>
    <div class="expand-me">
      <p>Extra Info: Donec eu nisl porta, convallis lectus eu, hendrerit libero. Morbi viverra lorem ut tellus tincidunt mattis. Curabitur nisi nulla, faucibus ut tempor non, varius sit amet nibh. Fusce nula tortor, convallis non ex ac, rhoncus dictum augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-footer">
      <p>Main Footer Stuff</p>
      <a class="expand">Expand!</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The jump is a bit jarring however but this is a great starting point for me.

Comment: which one satisfies your need? @user8792133